# Using .align in inline assemby

Tags: iphone, assembly

I'm using ".align 16 \n\t" in some inline ARM assembly that is implementing some loops
to align it on a 16 byte boundary however gcc asm compiler is complaining that alignement 
is too large

i want to implement -falign-loops=16 in asm for a particular loop

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `.align` directive for this particular CPU probably takes a power of 2 for the alignment argument, so to get 16 byte alignment you would need:

```
.align 4
```

Note that this directive behaves differently for different CPUs - see [tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC70](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC70)